# insert csv file into mssql if exists then update using apache nifi

Tags: sql-server, etl, apache-nifi

hi I have a csv file which will be generate for every 180 mins and should be inserted into ms sql
here is the sample csv file:-

```
id,name,address,pukcod,vihemida
 5,rahul,vedu,0949,thr
 6,ryhul,vydu,0669,thr
 7,verm,redr,0464,thr
```

the above csv file has to be inserted into mssql database in any case if id already exists then i need to update using apache nifi , i am using putdatabaserecord where i can only insert or update , if i choose update the new records are not inserting if i use insert then existing records are not getting updated is there any solution

for example :-
my existing mssql database has below records

```
id,name,address,pukcod,vihemida
 5,rahul,rem,0949,thr
```

now i have to insert the csv file records into my mssql database and if id exists then it should be updated in nifi

```
id,name,address,pukcod,vihemida
 5,rahul,vedu,0949,thr            <------ update record
 6,ryhul,vydu,0669,thr          | insert record
 7,verm,redr,0464,thr           | insert record
```

can any one helpme in solving this in nifi

Comment: If you were implementing this in SQL, then you would want an "upsert" or `MERGE`.

Comment: hi need to upsert @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using PutDatabaseRecord and using the UPSERT statement type.

E.g. GetFile -> PutDatabaseRecord, and use a CSVReader as the Record Reader.

Docs on PutDatabaseRecord here:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/

Docs on CSVReader here:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/index.html

Comment: UPSERT for MS SQL does not yet exist in NiFi